# Common Framework to test functionality

Tags: c#, .net

How to write / develop a common framework to test newly  added  functional test automatically.

This is what  we need: -
Our application should store all the method names which need to be tested.
Application should pick the method and  execute the  test.

In the table application should display  following : -

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Functionality | Test Name           | Status | Last Run Date |
|---------------|---------------------|------------------------|
| Login         | Login to the system |  Pass  | 1 Jan 2013    |
|               |---------------------|------------------------|
| Login         | Logout from system  |  Pass  | 1 Jan 2013    |
|---------------|---------------------|------------------------|
| Account       | Debit Money         |  Pass  | 1 Jan 2013    |
|               |---------------------|------------------------|
| Account       | Withdraw Money      |  Fail  | 1 Jan 2013    |
|---------------|---------------------|------------------------|
```

All above details should be stored in the database. Our application should pickup test and  run  the test periodically  (based on config settings).

Assuming that a developer had develop another functionality i.e. (Check Balance).

Now, what we want that developer should just feed the information in the database and our application should work as usual.

But the question is how we can achieve it? say developer had written new functionality (check balance) then only feeding one row in a database cannot be sufficient to run the test....as we should know how to execute checkbalance() method. etc.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Biiiiiiiiiggg question here - it's impossible to answer with a simple one-line reponse.  Q: Are you doing any C# unit testing already?  If not, why not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4, I had already gone through this link before..... but that doesn't answered my query? Even if we asked the developer to write the unit test for its own  functionality then also adding just one row cannot tell our  application  how  to execute it

Comment: Why would you want to run unit tests from within your application? Your code doesn't change after you compiled it, so you can just unit test the code.